# Even and Odd lines based assignment to variable

Tags: shell

I am trying to read the data from data from txt file. Below is the content of txt file.

```
http://google.com 
google  is working 
http://yahoo.com 
Yahoo is working
```

I am trying to assign the odd lines to variable A and even to variable B. So that I can run following command.

```
curl -s http://google.com  | grep -Po 'google  is working'
curl -s http://yahoo.com | grep -Po 'Yahoo is working'
```

I was trying to get it done using variable so that odd lines are automatically passed in curl and even in grep

```
curl -s $A | grep -Po $B
```

But I am unable to read the values and store it in variable.

Any suggestion will be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a simple `while loop` which should provide you with the required solution you are looking for.

```
while read -r odd_line
do
    echo "Odd line" $odd_line
    read -r even_line
    echo "Even line" $even_line
    curl -s "$odd_line" | grep -Po "even_line"
done < temp.txt
```

How it works
`temp.txt` is the file which contains you're data. This while loop reads `temp.txt` one line at a time. As expected, first line will be odd `odd_line` variable will hold odd line. Calling read again inside while loop will read even line. So `even_line` variable will contain even line. Once you have both variables define, you can pass them to any command

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
awk 'NR%2{url=$0;next} {system("curl -s \""url"\" | grep -Po \""$0"\"");}' file
```

**How it works:**

- `NR%2{url=$0;next}`

  If we are on an odd line, save its value to the variable `url` and skip on to the `next` line.

  This saves the whole line as the URL.  This means that you have to be careful that your line is actually a correct URL.  Trailing spaces should not be on the line unless they are actually part of the URL.
- `system("curl -s \""url"\" | grep -Po \""$0"\"")`

  Run the shell command that you want

#### Sample run

I made two changes to the test file: (1) trailing spaces were removed, and (2) the even lines were changed to match text that could be found:

```
$ cat file
http://google.com
TITLE.*TITLE
http://yahoo.com
TITLE.*TITLE
```

With this file, the above command produces the output:

```
$ awk 'NR%2{url=$0;next} {system("curl -s \""url"\" | grep -Po \""$0"\"");}' file
TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE
TITLE>Document Has Moved</TITLE
```

Comment: This is working for only 2nd row check . I mean it checks fine for yahoo but doesnt check for google.

Comment: @user2854333 It works for  me.  The `301 Moved` result is from google.  The `Document Has Moved` result is from yahoo.  Please check that you don't have any extraneous characters (like trailing white space) on the line with google's url.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat sample
this is odd
this is even
this is odd
this is even
```

This will print odd lines

```
sed -n 1~2p sample
this is odd
this is odd
```

This will print even lines

```
sed -n 2~2p sample
this is even
this is even
```

Use command substitution to store the `sed` output in any variable.

```
A=$(sed -n 2~2p sample)
```

`awk` version : check if line/record number is divisible by 2 or not.

```
awk ' NR % 2 != 0 { print; }' sample
this is odd
this is odd
awk ' NR % 2 == 0 { print; }' sample
this is even
this is even
```

Note: To maintain the integrity of the variable , double quote it while using it in `curl`. Otherwise all the lines will appear in single line.